# Matching end of ine in GREP

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have this piece of bash script which is supposed to match words that end with an 'a'. However, when I run this, I get no output, despite the fact that my text file has words that end with 'a'.

```
cat $1 | cut -d'|' -f3 | cut -d',' -f2 | sed 's/^ //' | egrep -i "a$"
```

If I remove the '$' it shows output, but with '$' it returns nothing. It still works, just doesn't match.

Would appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

A sample of the file

> MTNG1511|5013566|Xin, Mackenzie Darren MTNG9902|5079970|Park, Xue
>   Hannah Vanessa MTNG1511|5059072|Chung, Michael Jia Tianyu
>   MTNG1521|5060774|Lim, Stephanie Lauren MTNG1531|5060774|Lim, Stephanie
>   Lauren MTNG2521|5060774|Lim, Stephanie Lauren MTNG9020|5060538|Bi,
>   Samuel Shiyu MTNG9021|5060538|Bi, Samuel Shiyu MTNG9902|5072116|Hu,
>   Kai Zhi Patrick

Output should be

> Park, Xue Hannah Vanessa

Since it ends with an 'a'

Comment: Can you give a sample of the input file and the expected output ?

Comment: perhaps you have whitespace at the end of your word.

Comment: @hakanBaba sure. I have added a sample.

Comment: @jdigital I tried with "\n$", but it didn't seem to match. Maybe because that's not the right way to match a new line?

Comment: Are the lines correctly formatted in the input you specify ?
Do the lines start with MTN all the time ? Can one line have multiple `MTN...|<number>|<Name>` blocks ?

Comment: Also please use the code formatting not quote formatting.

Comment: Is there a newline between Darren and MTN...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably extra whitespace at the end of your word.

Try adding

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//'
```

to remove the whitespace -- or else change your grep to allow for whitespace at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah that worked. I tried removing the new line at the end before, but it didn't work. Does the \n or \t only work inside a []?

Comment: The problem isn't with the newline.  It's with the blank or tab character(s)  between the letter 'a' and the end of line.

Comment: You could do `\s*` instead of `[ \t]*` (if your sed supports it).  Just try it!

Answer (score 0):

**This is very simple using grep**

```
grep -o '[^\|]\+$' < "$1" | grep 'a\s*$'
```

**Output**

```
$ bash example file.txt 
Park, Xue Hannah Vanessa 
$
```

[^\|]\+ match one or more characters that aren't | to the end of the line.
a\s*$    match a as last character but check for some spaces before the line feed.